# JNA package exists but NetBeans import still says it does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, jna, vlcj

I am trying to create a media player on NetBeans using VLCJ. The code I found uses the following import:

```
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
```

It said "the package sun.com.jna does not exist" so I downloaded the package (jna-platform-4.0.0.jar) but when I add it to the application, it still says it does not exist. I have tried several different versions and the problem persists.

How can I correct this so that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA provides `jna.jar` (core library) and `jna-platform.jar` (platform-specific bindings).  You're missing the former.